# Dealing with Conflicting Wordpress Scripts

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, conflict

I'm writing a public release Wordpress plugin that uses the jQuery Flot script. After debugging something strange for hours, I discovered the problem: a different Wordpress plugin was loading an older version of Flot, and Wordpress was using that older version instead of mine, which is the most current.

This leads to my question: what's the best practice for handling conflicting versions of scripts inside Wordpress?

In my plugin, I am using wp_enqueue_script() to load my scripts on just my plugin's admin pages. Would it be reasonable to first run wp_deregister_script() for any script I fear may encounter conflicts?

Thank you!!

Comment: You could indeed run those deregister calls. I've seen plugins do that before. Keep in mind that you could break those other plugins if they're incompatible with your newer versions.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I agree about the possibility of breaking other plugins. What I'm doing is checking the $hook before (now deregistering) and enqueuing the scripts to make sure it only happens on my admin pages. I hope that's good enough to keep everyone's plugin running properly :)

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try and beat that other plugin to the punch by making your enqueue_script callback execute first.

do

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts', 0 );
```

and that will make your script queue first. That `0` will put it at the top of the `wp_enqueue_scripts` list. unless that other plugin is doing the same thing.

If that doesn't work then you might need to enqueue it last in which case you should use `PHP_INT_MAX` instead of `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My concern is like you said, what if they're doing the same? It's possible they are enqueuing first or even last already.